# VBA compare 2 columns and merge/cop

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, and I am looking for a simple VBA code to compare 2 rows and merge/copy data if there is a different in the sheets.

I want to compare column A in sheet 2 with column A in sheet 1.

If the ID in column A is equal to column A in sheet 1, update data in columns B and C with the data from sheet 1.

If the ID from sheet 1 isn’t present in sheet 2, add column A,B,C to sheet 2.

Does above make sense or?

BR
And.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not test all scenarios through this. Does something like this work for what you are trying to do?  This does make the assumption  that there is either 0 or 1 occurrence​ of the ID in Sheet2. Also, assumes that there are column headers in row 1 and not actual data.

```
Public Sub CheckSheet2()


    Dim source_sheet As Worksheet
    Set source_sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim source_last_row As Long
    source_last_row = source_sheet.Range("A" & source_sheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim target_sheet As Worksheet
    Set target_sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim target_last_row As Long
    target_last_row = target_sheet.Range("A" & target_sheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim source_row As Long
    For source_row = 2 To source_last_row

        Dim source_str As String
        source_str = source_sheet.Range("A" & source_row).Value

        Dim found_value As Range
        Set found_value = target_sheet.Range("A2:A" & target_last_row).Find(source_str)

        If Not found_value Is Nothing Then
            target_sheet.Range(found_value.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value = source_sheet.Range("B" & source_row).Value
            target_sheet.Range(found_value.Address).Offset(0, 2).Value = source_sheet.Range("C" & source_row).Value
        Else
            target_last_row = target_last_row + 1
            target_sheet.Range("A" & target_last_row).Value = source_sheet.Range("A" & source_row).Value
            target_sheet.Range("B" & target_last_row).Value = source_sheet.Range("B" & source_row).Value
            target_sheet.Range("C" & target_last_row).Value = source_sheet.Range("C" & source_row).Value
        End If

    Next source_row

End Sub
```

You will obviously need to change the values of Sheet1 and Sheet2 to your worksheet names.

before I ran the procedure I had something that looked like this in Sheet1.

[image]

And this was in Sheet2 before running the procedure. Notice ID 127 and 128 are missing.

[image]

This is what Sheet2 looked like after running the procedure.

[image]